# Describe the image of the set $G = \{ z \mid |z| >2, 0 < arg(z) \leq \pi\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Describe the image of the set $G = \{ z \mid |z| >2, 0 < arg(z) \leq \pi\}$ where $f(z) = z^3$

So $f(z) = r^3 ( \cos(3\theta) + i\sin(3\theta))$ and $r^3 > 2$.

So is it all points in the first and second quadrant such that their modulus is greater than $2$?

Comment: How could it be? The modulus gets cubed and the argument gets tripled.

Comment: @zhw. What do you mean? How could it not be? All we care about is that the modulus is greater than $2$.

Comment: @klpoo, $G$ consists of numbers in the 1st and 2nd quadrant with modulus greater than 2. But the question is about the *image* of $G$, presumably under the mapping $f$, though you don't actually say so. This is the set $f(G) = \{f(z) | z \in G\}$, Which is different from $G$.